# How to accept 2D arrays in Spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I'm making a POST request via jQuery Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: opts.save_url,
    data: $(ul_obj).serializeFormList() + "&form_id=" + form_db_id,
});
```

The `$(ul_obj).serializeFormList()` creates a 2D array of request params.
Here's the screengrab of the params passed to the Spring MVC controller:

[image]

Now when I handle this in the Controller I get 404 Bad Request for `frmb[][]`
Here's the code:

```
public @ResponseBody String saveData(@RequestParam(value= "form_id", required = true) String formId, 
                                    @RequestParam(value= "frmb", required = true) String[][] formArray) {

                //Content removed for brevity
                }
```

What is the exact way to handle this request data? Please guide me. I'm stuck real bad.

Comment: Java has only integer indexes, you are sending integer **and** strings. Try making them all only integers.

Answer (score 2):

As I see you are concatenating the parameters

```
"&form_id=" + form_db_id
```

you can do the same for "frmb"

```
frmb=1,2&frmb=2,3
```

so when you try get the String [][] using

```
@RequestParam(value= "frmb", required = true) String[][] formArray)
```

you will get

```
formArray = [[1,2],[2,3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has only index (integer) based Arrays:

So either you make your request using only integer based arrays:

```
 form_Id
 frmb[0][0] input_text
 frmb[0][1] required
 frmb[0][values] sdfsfds
```

or you use an other structure to fetch the data: For example an Array containing a Map

```
@RequestParam(value= "frmb", required = true) Map<String,String>[] formArray
```

If you are able to modify the sended json, then I would recommend to use a JavaBean instead of the Map