# Convert javascript array into two dimensional object array in Java

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, multidimensional-array

I have passed an 2 dimensional array like this using ajax to servlet

```
var data = [["BSC","Name","Code"],[34,"dfg4",34],[345,"3dg4sdfd",345],[234,"dfg4","34f"],[23,"dfg4","s34"],[23,"dg","wdr3"],[234,244,"drydr"]];

$.ajax({
        url: './SubmitSheet',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'json': JSON.stringify(data)},
        success: function () {
    }
});
```

In servlet I need to retrieve the values to a 2 dimensional array
I have tried using

```
String data[] = request.getParameterValues("json");
```

But it puts all the values into 0 index (data[0])

Comment: You have to iterate and populate

Comment: If it's `bidimensional` why you instantiate an `unidimensional` `data[]` array instead of `data[][]`?

Comment: Also, read this question, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067073/initialising-a-multidimensional-array-in-java

Comment: Enumeration en=req.getParameterNames();
 
  while(en.hasMoreElements())
  {
   Object objOri=en.nextElement();
   String param=(String)objOri;
   String value=req.getParameter(param);
   pw.println("Parameter Name is '"+param+"' and Parameter Value is '"+value+"'");
  }

Comment: This might help you.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040926/how-to-accept-2d-arrays-in-spring-mvc-controller

Answer (score 0):

You code should be:

```
String data = request.getParameter("json");
```

You will need to parse the String try using [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: How is this any different from his actual code?

Comment: This code won't even compile

Comment: code updated. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568142/how-to-read-json-sent-by-ajax-in-servlet for more info

Comment: Next time you fiund a duplicate, vote/flag for close as duplicate.

Comment: I would if I had those powers. They are granted back tomorrow...

Answer (score -1):

try this method. Change value of input as necessary.

```
private static void jsArrayToJavaArray(){
    String input = "[[\"BSC\",\"Name\",\"Code\"],[34,\"dfg4\",34]," +
            "[345,\"3dg4sdfd\",345],[234,\"dfg4\",\"34f\"],[23,\"dfg4\",\"s34\"]," +
            "[23,\"dg\",\"wdr3\"],[234,244,\"drydr\"]]";

    input = input.substring(2,input.lastIndexOf("]"));
    input = input.substring(0,input.lastIndexOf("]"));

    String outerArr[] = input.split("],\\[");
    String output[][]= new String[outerArr.length][];
    for(int i=0;i<outerArr.length;i++){
        output[i] = outerArr[i].split(",");
    }

    //print results
    for(int i=0;i<output.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<output[i].length;j++){
            System.out.println(output[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: may I know the reason for down vote?